# SQL/Hive How to combine two different queries into one result with different columns

Tags: sql, hive

Sorry if the title sucks.
I would like to basically convert both of these queries into one query with the result having two columns:

`select count(columnA) as prev from myTable where set_id = 1530880217;`

`select count(columnA) as curr from myTable where set_id = 1530901756;`

Output:

```
prev | curr

1000 | 1500
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(case when set_id = 1530880217 then 1 else 0 end) as prev,
       sum(case when set_id = 1530901756 then 1 else 0 end) as curr
from myTable
where set_id in (1530880217, 1530901756);
```

This assumes that `columnA` is never `NULL`.  If you really want the `NULL` check:

```
select sum(case when set_id = 1530880217 and ColumnA is not null then 1 else 0 end) as prev,
       sum(case when set_id = 1530901756 and ColumnA is not null then 1 else 0 end) as curr
from myTable
where set_id in (1530880217, 1530901756);
```

Comment: Should that be set_id in (1530880217, 1530901756)